# Goal seek in R with 3 parameters

Tags: r, optimization

```
#========
#DATABASE
#========
database <- matrix(c(51,43,-22,-92,28,-21,68,22,9,-20,-30,-1,-10,10,-10,-5,10,-2,30,-3,-5),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(database ) <- c("A","B","C")
database  <- as.data.frame(database )
x<-1
y<-1
z<-1
database$RES<-c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1)
database$SCORE<- database$A*x+database$B*y+database$C*z
database$PREV<- ifelse(database$SCORE>1,1,0)

#========
#TARGET
#========
t<-table(database$RES, database$PREV)
P<-(t[1]+t[4])/nrow(database)
```

This is an example of my database (60k rows), I want to find values for x y z (in the code I put "1" just for convenience to run the script but I want to find them!) to have maximum value of P. The target P must be 1 or closed to 1.

I didnt find what I'm looking for in thread with similiar title. 
In excel is pretty simple but can't find more than 1 parameter.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not satisfied with this answer, but maybe this is something that can at least get you started.

The `optim()` function finds the optimum set of answers for the problem you're trying to solve, but it looks to me, at least with the toy data, that it finds itself into a local maxima. You'd have to run it several times to find the best parameters, for me it occurs when `P = 0.8571429`, and even then the `x`, `y`, `z` values can vary quite significantly, which would indicate that there are several equally optimal solutions for this particular data.

```
database <- matrix(c(51,43,-22,-92,28,-21,68,22,9,-20,-30,-1,-10,10,-10,-5,10,-2,30,-3,-5),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(database ) <- c("A","B","C")
database  <- as.data.frame(database )
database$RES <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1)

find_best <- function(data, x) {
  SCORE <- data$A*x[1]+data$B*x[2]+data$C*x[3]
  PREV <- ifelse(SCORE>1,1,0)
  t <- table(data$RES, PREV)
  P <- (t[1]+t[4])/nrow(data)
  P
}

result <- optim(c(1, 1, 1), find_best, data = database, method = "SANN", control = list(fnscale = -1))

result$value
[1] 0.8571429 # The P value

result$par
[1]  2.396844 -4.460343 -7.137460 # These are your sought after x, y, z parameters.
```

Comment: how to limit the parameters? for example only positive or 0<x<100 or only integer numbers. 

In the otpim() help I found "lower" and "upper" but only for L-BFGS-B and Brent Method and doesnt work. However it seems doesnt work with my data. I found better result with manual values that with optim. With repeat command and rowMeans I hope to find a good approximation

Comment: Like I said, I'm not satisfied with my answer, but I don't know what more to do. Maybe someone can build on it and improve it.